# After successful login: AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the strange problem that after I logged in, I can make *one* request and after that every following request throws a Spring `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException`. I have no idea why this is the case.

In my `LoginService` I use my injected `AdminAuthenticationProvider` to log the user in:

```
public class LoginService {

    private AuthenticationProvider adminAuthenticationProvider;     

    public LoginService(DSLContext ctx, AuthenticationProvider adminAuthenticationProvider) {       
        this.adminAuthenticationProvider = adminAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void login(String userId, String password) {

        CustomUserDetails user = new CustomUserDetails(userId, password, true, true, true, true, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password,
                new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());     

        try {
            auth = this.adminAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(auth);
        } catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
        sc.setAuthentication(auth);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);       
    }
}
```

The `AdminAuthenticationProvider` implementation:

```
public class AdminAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private RestaurantAdminRepository restaurantAdminRepository;

    public AdminAuthenticationProvider(DSLContext ctx) {
        this.restaurantAdminRepository = new RestaurantAdminRepository(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");

        Authentication customAuthentication = new CustomUserAuthentication(roles, authentication);
        customAuthentication.setAuthenticated(true);

        return customAuthentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

As you can see nothing really gets checked here, the user just gets logged in.
However, after that I am always getting the exception. Currently I am only using `isAuthenticated()`.

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public List<StoreDTO> getAvailableStores() {        
    // ..
    return result;
}
```

What could be the problem here?

---

This is my configuration **applicationContext-spring-acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Imports -->
    <import resource="applicationContext-jooq.xml"/>

    <!-- See 15.3.2 Built-In Expression @http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-permission-evaluator -->
    <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <!-- To use hasPermission() in expressions, configure a PermissionEvaluator -->
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
        <property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mahlzeit.server.web.auth.permission.CustomAclPermissionEvaluator" id="permissionEvaluator">
        <constructor-arg ref="aclService" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare an acl service -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService"  id="aclService">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy" />
        <constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a lookup strategy -->
    <bean id="lookupStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
        <constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy" />
        <constructor-arg ref="auditLogger" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare an acl cache -->
    <bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
                <property name="cacheManager">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:shared="true"/>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ACL_ADMIN" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>      
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare an acl authorization strategy -->
    <bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare an audit logger -->
    <bean id="auditLogger"
        class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger" />

    <!-- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html -->
    <bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
                ROLE_USER > ROLE_VISITOR
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <sec:global-method-security authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" pre-post-annotations="enabled">   
        <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>       
    </sec:global-method-security>
</beans>
```

And this is **applicationContext-spring-security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd"    
    >

    <!-- Imports -->
    <import resource="applicationContext-spring-acl.xml"/>

    <sec:http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"/>

    <bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
        <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationListener" class="com.mahlzeit.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationListener"/>

    <bean id="adminAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mahlzeit.server.web.auth.AdminAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="dslContext" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mahlzeit.server.web.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="adminAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

---

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.mz.server.web.servlet.StoreServletImpl - Requested available stores.
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List com.mz.server.web.service.StoreService.getAvailableStores(); target is of class [com.mz.server.web.service.StoreService]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'isAuthenticated()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
[http-bio-8080-exec-3] TRACE org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19c3e3e: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundEvent[source=ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List com.mz.server.web.service.RestaurantService.getAvailableStores(); target is of class [com.mz.server.web.service.StoreService]]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.mahlzeit.server.web.service.RestaurantService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9012bad4_3.getAvailableRestaurants(<generated>)
    at com.mahlzeit.server.web.servlet.RestaurantServletImpl.getAvailableRestaurants(RestaurantServletImpl.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
sc.setAuthentication(auth);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);
```

to:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

In case of `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` usage you want to bind this auth object to the whole session, [not only to the request](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence).

Comment: Okay, more or less. Is there something like a timeout?

Comment: Timeout?? Can you explain what do you experience?

Comment: I logged in and I was writing to you on SO. After one or two minutes I sent another request and I got the exception again. But maybe that was something else. I'll test it a few times and let you know :)

Comment: Yep, there it was again. The time it took me to answer you seems to be enough and the exception returns O_o If I keep requesting the errors does not seem to occur ..

Comment: Uhhh. Sorry. No clear answer on this, just guessing: some unwanted restart in the background? (auto-publish or something can cause that) / Anything relevant in the log maybe? The shortest session timeout variable I have seen was 30 min.

Comment: No, the server does not restart. :/ Could it be the cache? I am using EhCache but did not configure anything yet. Could it be that the cache does that to me?

Comment: Cache? I don't think so. Not sure, but I cannot imagine how could that interfere here. The only strange thing I see right now is the `@Transactional` annotation on your login method. Everything else seems to be by the book. I need to leave for some time, but will be back in an hour. If you can't solve it quickly, I would enable TRACE level logging, that would surely show what is going on.

Comment: Thanks I will try it with some more logging. :)

Comment: I am back. Any luck?

Comment: I added the exception I am getting with `TRACE` but I am not sure how this can help me here :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100514/discussion-between-gergely-bacso-and-stefan-falk).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your LoginService is integrated with Spring Security.  I would consider a custom user details service:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService extends JdbcUserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
```

And then integrate that into your SecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ....
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean here.

Comment: Instead of your login service, which is doing a lot of unnecessary work that Spring does for you, either use the vanilla Spring user details service (e.g. JdbcUserDetailsManager) or write your own custom one.

Comment: Gergely was right with his answer. But thank you for trying to help! :)

Comment: `com.mahlzeit.server.web.service.CustomUserDetailsService` is already defined in applicationContext-spring-security.xml.